# How to get Message more efficiently From Yammer when the user input by using java?

Tags: java, rest, yammer

Now I am creating a chat bot to communicate with Yammer using Java.
As a method of acquiring a message when the user inputs it with Yammer,
I'm getting the following REST APIs at 1 second intervals.
https://www.yamer.com/api/v1/messages.json
With this method, loading is applied to the Yammer server side, and I think whether there is a more efficient way.
Is there a way to get messages only when a message is posted to a chat bot user for a specific user?
Or is there any other way?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only way to learn whether there are new messages in a given Yammer feed is to poll the messages.json endpoint. We recognize that a push-based method, like webhooks, would be better for developers and the performance of the Yammer service and we're looking into when we can prioritize building this out.

Comment: Thanks Neil.Such a method like a push-based method is still a future task.Even knowing it was helpful.

Comment: For others. It seems that this is still the way to go forward. So far I have not been able to find any webhook or other means than polling the above mentioned url.